# How to solve the inequality $x^2>10$ using square roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

Solve the inequality: $$x^2>10$$

How am I supposed to do this? It doesn't make sense when I take into account that if $x^2=10$ then $x=+\sqrt{10}$ and $x=-\sqrt{10}$

But how am I supposed to apply this to an inequality, I would get $x>\sqrt{10}$ and $x>-\sqrt{10}$

But for some reason this just doesn't make sense to me.  Can someone explain it to me mathematically, instead of just having to memorize these kinds of things?

Comment: Try $x=-3$ and $x=-4$ and check your inequality for the negative square root.

Comment: It would be $x > \sqrt{x}$ or $x < - \sqrt{10}$ i.e. $x\in\mathbb{R} - [-\sqrt{10},\sqrt{10}]$

Comment: $x=+\sqrt{10}\text{ and }x=-\sqrt{10}$ is a contradiction. Your solution of $x^2=10$ should instead be $x=+\sqrt{10}\text{ or }x=-\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Rather than saying that your inequality is "basic", it is better to say what it actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem you have here lies in understanding the difference between **and** and **or**.

Concerning the equation $x^2=10$, your statement $$x=+\surd10\quad\text{ and }\quad x=−\surd10$$ is self-contradictory and false. Correct is:$$x=+\surd10\quad\text{or}\quad x=−\surd10.$$Similarly, as you already point out regarding the inequality $x^2>10$, the statement  $$x>+\surd10\quad\text{ and }\quad x<−\surd10$$makes little sense. The correct version is$$x>+\surd10\quad\text{or}\quad x<−\surd10.$$

Answer (score 31):

Sketch the graph of $x^2$ (it's a parabola opening upwards with vertex in $(0,0)$) and sketch the line $y=10$.

[image]

They intersect in $x=-\sqrt{10}$ and $x=\sqrt{10}$, and the sketch immediately gives the solution to the inequality:

$$x<-\sqrt{10} \vee x>\sqrt{10}$$

Comment: Very visual, very nice.

Comment: What software do you use to plot this function?

Comment: It's a free online tool: Desmos.

Answer (score 29):

Using $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, we get $(x-\sqrt{10})(x+\sqrt{10}) > 0$, which mean $x+\sqrt{10}$ and $x-\sqrt{10}$ have the same sign

Comment: Nice answer! This is how I like to do it. Just using the basic properties of numbers is more appealing to me than using the graphical approach.

Comment: When solving polynomial inequalities, it's often best to collect and factor.  Then sorting each factor from least to greatest (when all of the factors are of degree one) will lead you to find the correct intervals.

Answer (score 21):

Another (perhaps more systematic?) approach:

$$x^2 > 10 \Leftrightarrow |x| > \sqrt{10} \Leftrightarrow x > +\sqrt{10}\ \lor\ x < -\sqrt{10}$$

Answer (score 10):

Another way to see it algebraicaly/analyticaly is this:

$(-x)^2 = x^2 > 10$ then you have 2 conditions:

a)  $-x > \sqrt{10} \implies x < -\sqrt{10}$

b)  $x > \sqrt{10}$

which both provide solutions

Comment: I like this. Very neat :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I think about problems like this:

If $x^2 > 10$, then

$x^2 - 10 > 0$

$(x + \sqrt {10})(x - \sqrt {10}) > 0 $

$(x + \sqrt {10})$ and $(x - \sqrt {10})$ are either both positive or both negative.

Thus, when they are both positive and we divide both sides by one of the terms:

$x + \sqrt {10} > 0$ and $x - \sqrt {10} > 0$

This simplifies to:

$x > \sqrt {10}$

When they are both negative and we divide both sides by one of the terms:

$x + \sqrt {10} < 0$ and $x - \sqrt {10} < 0$

This simplifies to:

$x < -\sqrt {10}$

The **final solution** is:

$x < -\sqrt {10}$ or $x > \sqrt {10}$

---

Conversely,

if $x^2 < 10$, then

$x^2 - 10 < 0$

$(x - \sqrt{10})(x + \sqrt{10}) < 0$

We know that one of the terms, $(x - \sqrt{10})$ or $(x + \sqrt{10})$, is negative.

Since $(x - \sqrt{10})$ is always smaller, we know that it is the negative term.

Thus, when we divide both sides by $(x - \sqrt{10})$ we get:

$x + \sqrt{10} > 0$

This simplifies to:

$x > -\sqrt{10}$

when we divide both sides by $(x + \sqrt{10})$ we get:

$x - \sqrt{10} < 0$

This simplifies to:

$x < \sqrt{10}$

The **final solution** is:

$-\sqrt {10} < x < \sqrt {10}$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2>10$

$\sqrt{x^2} > \sqrt{10}$

$|x| > \sqrt{10}$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x > \sqrt{10} &\mbox{, if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x>\sqrt{10} &\mbox{, if $x < 0$}
\end{array}
\right.
\
$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x > \sqrt{10} &\mbox{, if $x \geq 0$}\\
x<-\sqrt{10} &\mbox{, if $x < 0$}
\end{array}
\right.
\
$

Therefore, $x > \sqrt{10}$, or, $x<-\sqrt{10}$

Answer (score -1):

One way to think about this is as a graph.  What happens if you plot $y= x^2$?  You get a parabola.  Now, for which values of $x$ is $y > 10$?  The answer is $x>\sqrt{10}$ and $x<\sqrt{10}$.

You can see a graph like this here:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%3D+10

Answer (score -1):

A quadratic equation usually has two solutions (except *x*<sup>2</sup>=0 etc.). Consequently, a quadratic inequality such at this one has two sets of solutions, in this case one positive and one negative.